# Какие числа нужно писать раздельно, а какие — вместе?

Tags: числительные, число, пробелы

Насколько я знаю, многие числа в русской письменности принято разделять по три разряда справа: стоимость (12 000 рублей), количество (3 200 светодиодов) и т. д. Но есть и случаи, когда числа, вроде бы, не разделяют: частоту (1200 МГц), ёмкость (5000 мА⋅ч) и т. д.

Есть ли какое-то правило на этот счёт, указывающее, какие числа нужно разделять по три разряда справа, а какие — нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сошлюсь на Грамота.ру: «Если цифр в числе пять и больше, то, как правило, используются пробелы, отделяющие по три цифры справа: 89 645, 4 028 880». Правильно будет не разделять пробелом первые два класса (т. е. число четырехзначное).

Наряду с этой версией бытует и другая: «пробелом разделяются каждые три цифры в пятизначных, а по некоторым правилам — и в четырехзначных числах, например: 50 000, 7 985 и т. д.».

Справочник художественного и технического редакторов (Пинхус Гиленсон) даёт такие рекомендации:

> Многозначные числа, набираемые арабскими цифрами, классы (по три цифры
> справа налево) разбивают шпациями 2-п. (3 245 758). **Разбивку на классы
> не делают для четырёхзначных чисел, десятичных дробей** и для
> обозначения номеров и стандартов (0,01599, ГОСТ 16598—75).

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, но добавлю в комментарии, что при использовании разделительного пробела его нужно делать неразрывным. В противном случае лучше вообще его не использовать, я считаю.